# Render javascript via json object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am working on a public api in rails, something very simple.
Currently I have an jsonp callback in my tag class that looks like the following when invoked.

JSON:

```
{
    "tag": 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "tag_code": "<script type=\"text\/javascript\">alert(\"hello world\");      <\/script>"
    }
}
```

my goal is to get this code onto a remote page.

I have tried using ajax to do so, However I am to understand that jquery does not allow for external script tags to be loaded onto a page for security purposes.

JQuery on remote page

```
function fetchTagData(id) 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://localhost:3000/tag/" + id + ".js",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "GET",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            var code = data['tag']['tag_code'];
            console.log(code);
            $('#test').append(code);
        }
    });
};
```

when I view the console i see the js in all of its glory and the alert box appears. When I view source or inspect element the js is not on the page.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can get the js to appear on the page using a similar method or the same?

Comment: If you use the traditional "view source" function, you'll see the page as it was when it was loaded.

Comment: Chrome and Firebug on Firefox has inspectors that let you see how the document looks like at any given time.

Comment: The data you posted is JSON, yet you tell jQuery to expect JSONP. That won't work. JSONP is nothing else than including an external JavaScript file. JSON by itself is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling JSON by itself is  a valid javascript that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does `#test` actually exist? What is the outcome of `$('#test')` in your console?

Comment: @Jan: Nope. If you literally put `{"tag":...}` into the source, you will get a syntax error, because the `{...}` are interpreted as *block*. That's why you cannot load JSON as JSONP. It's not valid JavaScript by itself.

Comment: When i call $('#test') in the console i get back the empty div element. <div id="test"></div>

Comment: @felix I am calling the part of the json by the following data['tag']['tag_code'] so i access only that particular "value" of the json object.

Comment: It does not matter... the data will never be parsed if you load JSON as JSONP. Don't you see any error in the console?

Comment: no errors show up at all when the page loads. The alert box fires but the test div has no data in it. If i change       dataType: "jsonp"
 to       dataType: "json" then an access error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

json like this

```
{
   "tag": 
   {
      "id": 1,
      "tag_code": "alert(\"hello world\");"
   }
}
```

run code using **eval**

```
function fetchTagData(id) 
{
$.ajax(
{
    url: "http://localhost:3000/tag/" + id + ".js",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "GET",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
        var code = data['tag']['tag_code'];
        console.log(code);
        eval(code);
    }
});
};
```